# Avoid double switch case in strategy pattern

Tags: c#, switch-statement, strategy-pattern

I know this is a lot of stuff but please bear with me, I don't know how else to describe the problem comprehensively. Imagine there is a mashine which has 2 devices `A` & `B`. Each of the devices has 2 axes that can be turned on and off. (The axes have actually more properties to set, but for the sake of simplicity let's focus only on 1):

```
        mashine
           |
      ------------
      |          |
      A          B
    ------    ------
    |    |    |    |
    X    Y    X    Y
   ---  ---  ---  ---
   |||  |||  |||  |||
   ESP  ESP  ESP  ESP

E: Enable(bool) | S: Start(bool) | P: Position(double)
```

The mashine is represented by the following class (which I cannot change!):

// MASHINE

```
public static class Mashine
{
    public static bool Enable_B_X { get; set; }
    public static bool Enable_B_Y { get; set; }

    public static bool Enable_A_X { get; set; }
    public static bool Enable_A_Y { get; set; }
    // actually much more properties for each axis and device
}
```

My aim is to program a control class which would provide methods that can be used to set these variables. I tried using a strategy pattern (or at least something similar to this). The pattern of the mashine parts tree lead me to try to apply the pattern twice (since it has 2 split levels). Once in the interchangeable devices and one in the interchangeable axes.   This is the code I have so far:

// Device Control Interface and the 2 Different Device Classes A and B

```
public class DeviceControl
{
    public virtual IAxis Axis { get; set; }

    public void Enable()
    {
        Axis.Enable = true;
    }
    public void Disable()
    {
        Axis.Enable = false;
    }
}

public class DeviceControl_A : DeviceControl
{
    public override IAxis Axis
    {
        get { return base.Axis as IAxis_A; }
        set { base.Axis = value as IAxis_A; }
    }
}

public class DeviceControl_B : DeviceControl
{
    public override IAxis Axis
    {
        get { return base.Axis as IAxis_B; }
        set { base.Axis = value as IAxis_B; }
    }
}
```

Axis representation (Interface and Explicit Classes): Basically they are intended to map the variables in the `static` class `Mashine` onto the properties of the different axes

```
public interface IAxis
{
    bool Enable { get; set; }
}

// These Interfaces are to ensure that Axis_A goes only into Device A
// and Axis_B only with device B
public interface IAxis_A : IAxis { }

public interface IAxis_B : IAxis { }

public class X_Axis_A : IAxis_A
{
    public bool Enable
    {
        get => Mashine.Enable_A_X;
        set => Mashine.Enable_A_X = value;
    }
}

public class Y_Axis_A : IAxis_A
{
    public bool Enable
    {
        get => Mashine.Enable_A_Y;
        set => Mashine.Enable_A_Y = value;
    }
}

public class X_Axis_B : IAxis_B
{
    public bool Enable
    {
        get => Mashine.Enable_B_X;
        set => Mashine.Enable_B_X = value;
    }
}

public class Y_Axis_B : IAxis_B
{
    public bool Enable
    {
        get => Mashine.Enable_B_Y;
        set => Mashine.Enable_B_Y = value;
    }
}
```

And this is the Control Class which provides the methods for the control of the mashine in dependency of the device and the appropriate axis:

```
public enum Device { A, B }

public enum Axis { X, Y }


public class Control
{
    public DeviceControl devControl;

    public void Disable(Device dev, Axis dim)
    {
        // initialize
        InitAxisAndDevice(dev, dim);
        devControl.Disable();       
    }

    public void Enable(Device dev, Axis dim)
    {
        InitAxisAndDevice(dev, dim);
        devControl.Enable();
    }


    private void InitAxisAndDevice(Device dev, Axis dim)
    {
        switch (dev)
        {
            case Device.A:
                this.devControl = new DeviceControl_A();

                switch (dim)
                {
                    case Axis.X: this.devControl.Axis = new X_Axis_A(); break;
                    case Axis.Y: this.devControl.Axis = new Y_Axis_A(); break;
                    case Axis.Z: this.devControl.Axis = new Z_Axis_A(); break;
                }
                break;
            case Device.B:
                this.devControl = new DeviceControl_B();

                switch (dim)
                {
                    case Axis.X: this.devControl.Axis = new X_Axis_B(); break;
                    case Axis.Y: this.devControl.Axis = new Y_Axis_B(); break;
                    case Axis.Z: this.devControl.Axis = new Z_Axis_B(); break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Question 1**

How can I avoid this double switch case in the `InitAxisAndDevice` method?

**Question 2**

Is there a better way to make sure that only A-type axes go along with device A ?

I have the strong feeling that I misunderstood something in the application of this pattern. Is there maybe a different approach/pattern which would be more suitable to solve this mapping of control problem?

Any help is greatly appriciated. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Since I was too vague in explanation, here is a use case.
All axes have an almost identical set of variables that have to be set like:[enable(bool), position(double), start(bool)]

The point of abstraction is to have a single control class which can use one method `Enable` f.e. to enable any axis dependent on the type of device and on the type of axis.

I hope it became a little clearer

Comment: I think that to say you overcomplicated things is an understatement. I've read your question three times and still not sure I understand what your code does, or what your goal is. For instance, What's the point of `public interface IAxis_A : IAxis { }`? Please try to describe your  desired `Control` interface (that is, public methods you need).

Comment: I don't even really see the strategy pattern you are talking about.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thank you for your comment. It is an attempt to make things differently, I guess I overengineered. The control interface is intended to set the variables in the machine representation and write it down to the PLC. Depending on the type of device and the type of axis it is supposed to set the appropriate variable and write it to the PLC which is running on the mashine.

Comment: @Fildor it might well be that I misunderstood the implementation of the pattern, but the general idea is to set different variable dependent on the type. So that the call of `DeviceControl.Enabled` sets the appropiate variable fiting to the type of device and the type of axis and sends it to the PLC

Comment: It would be good if you explain more clearly how you plan to **use** your abstraction. There is no real need for abstraction unless you have the same code running for different devices/axis at some point.

Comment: @grek40 basically all axes have the same set of parameters [enable, position, velocity, startBit, stopBit] and both devices have the same set of axes [X,Y,Z] I would like to make 1 method to set a certain parameter depending on the type of device and the axis. Does that make sense? I have to deal with the representation class of the mashine. which works as an interface between my program and the PLC

Comment: No, it doesn't really make sense. This is the first time that you talk about parameters (a 3rd topic next to devices and axis). Also, if your actual action depends on the actual device and actual axis, then all uniform abstraction of devices and actions will only blow up the code. However, I'll post a proposed wrapper structure as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code. The idea is to create an abstract representation of device axis, devices and machine as interface. Then use a factory to create concrete devices and axis for the (given not changeable) `Mashine`.

```
public static class Mashine
{
    public static bool Enable_B_X { get; set; }
    public static bool Enable_B_Y { get; set; }

    public static bool Enable_A_X { get; set; }
    public static bool Enable_A_Y { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents a single axis of a single device
/// </summary>
public interface IDeviceAxis
{
    void Enable();
    void Disable();
}
// general device that has two axis, but doesn't care about anything else
public interface IDevice
{
    IDeviceAxis X { get; }
    IDeviceAxis Y { get; }
}
// data model for an alternative Mashine representation
public interface IMachineModel
{
    IDevice A { get; }
    IDevice B { get; }
}
```

Usage:

```
public enum Device { A, B }

public enum Axis { X, Y }

// your control class
public class Control
{
    public IMachineModel devControl;

    public Control()
    {
        // MachineFactory see below
        devControl = MachineFactory.GetMachine();
    }

    public void Disable(Device dev, Axis dim)
    {
        GetAxis(dev, dim).Disable();
    }

    public void Enable(Device dev, Axis dim)
    {
        GetAxis(dev, dim).Enable();
    }

    private IDeviceAxis GetAxis(Device dev, Axis dim)
    {
        var device = GetDevice(dev);
        switch (dim)
        {
            case Axis.X:
                return device.X;
            case Axis.Y:
                return device.Y;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Axis", "dim");
        }
    }
    private IDevice GetDevice(Device dev)
    {
        switch (dev)
        {
            case Device.A:
                return devControl.A;
            case Device.B:
                return devControl.B;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Device", "dev");
        }
    }
}
```

The missing part: a concrete implementation of the interfaces and a factory to get the whole machine representation:

```
// concrete machine factory
public static class MachineFactory
{
    // factory for the whole Mashine wrapper
    public static IMachineModel GetMachine()
    {
        return new MachineModel
        {
            A = GetDeviceA(),
            B = GetDeviceB(),
        };
    }

    // factory methods specify the connection from the wrapper classes to the Mashine

    private static IDevice GetDeviceA()
    {
        return new MachineDevice(x => Mashine.Enable_A_X = x, y => Mashine.Enable_A_Y = y);
    }
    private static IDevice GetDeviceB()
    {
        return new MachineDevice(x => Mashine.Enable_B_X = x, y => Mashine.Enable_B_Y = y);
    }

    // concrete implementations can be used for the target Mashine

    private class MachineDeviceAxis : IDeviceAxis
    {
        Action<bool> _setterFunction;
        public MachineDeviceAxis(Action<bool> setter)
        {
            _setterFunction = setter;
        }

        public void Enable()
        {
            _setterFunction(true);
        }

        public void Disable()
        {
            _setterFunction(false);
        }
    }

    private class MachineDevice : IDevice
    {
        public MachineDevice(Action<bool> xSetter, Action<bool> ySetter)
        {
            X = new MachineDeviceAxis(xSetter);
            Y = new MachineDeviceAxis(ySetter);
        }
        public IDeviceAxis X { get; private set; }

        public IDeviceAxis Y { get; private set; }
    }

    private class MachineModel : IMachineModel
    {
        public IDevice A { get; set; }

        public IDevice B { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Regarding the usage of the machine abstraction, I think there is no real advantage of using `enum Device` and `enum Axis`. Compare the following codes:

```
// controllers
Control yourControl;
IMachineModel myMachineModel;
// usage
yourControl.Enable(Device.A, Axis.X);
myMachineModel.A.X.Enable();
```

The advantage of using `Control` here doesn't really improve the code if you ask me.

**Edit regarding other parameters**

Maybe the `Enable` and `Disable` is already over-engineered? How about some generic `Set(value)` instead:

```
public interface IAxisParameter<TParameter>
{
    void Set(TParameter value);
}

public interface IDeviceAxis
{
    IAxisParameter<bool> Enabled { get; }

    IAxisParameter<double> Position { get; }

    IAxisParameter<bool> Start { get; }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Control
{
    public void Disable(Device dev, Axis dim)
    {
        GetAxis(dev, dim).Enabled.Set(false);
    }

    public void Enable(Device dev, Axis dim)
    {
        GetAxis(dev, dim).Enabled.Set(true);
    }

    // rest of the code as in the original answer above
}
```

Then change the internal machine implementation accordingly:

```
// inside factory

    // added implementation
    private class MachineParameter<TParam> : IAxisParameter<TParam>
    {
        Action<TParam> _setterFunction;
        public MachineParameter(Action<TParam> setter)
        {
            _setterFunction = setter;
        }
        public void Set(TParam value)
        {
            _setterFunction(value);
        }
    }

    // changed implementation
    private class MachineDeviceAxis : IDeviceAxis
    {
        public IAxisParameter<bool> Enabled { get; set; }

        public IAxisParameter<double> Position { get; set; }

        public IAxisParameter<bool> Start { get; set; }
    }

    // changed factory methods

    private static IDeviceAxis GetDeviceAxisA_X()
    {
        return new MachineDeviceAxis
        {
            Enabled = new MachineParameter<bool>(x => Mashine.Enable_A_X = x),
            Position = null, // TODO
            Start = null, // TODO
        };
    }
    private static IDeviceAxis GetDeviceAxisA_Y()
    {
        return new MachineDeviceAxis
        {
            Enabled = new MachineParameter<bool>(y => Mashine.Enable_A_Y = y),
            Position = null, // TODO
            Start = null, // TODO
        };
    }
    private static IDevice GetDeviceA()
    {
        return new MachineDevice
        {
            X = GetDeviceAxisA_X(),
            Y = GetDeviceAxisA_Y(),
        };
    }
    private static IDevice GetDeviceB()
    {
        // TODO same thing for device B
        return null;
    }
```

The concept should be clear... in the end you have to write some code for each property of the actual machine.
Maybe it would be a good idea to re-organize the parameter creation inside the factory to something like @Fildor did in his linked code example.

**Edit: keeping the factory code more compact**

Instead of bloating the factory with a separate method for each parameter, re-group the creation of parameter setters to create the setters for one parameter type in all devices in one place (eg. `CreateEnabledParameterSetters`):

```
// concrete machine factory
public static class MachineFactory
{
    // factory for the whole Mashine wrapper
    public static IMachineModel GetMachine()
    {
        var enabledSetters = CreateEnabledParameterSetters();
        return new MachineModel
        {
            A = GetDevice(enabledSetters, 0 /*A*/),
            B = GetDevice(enabledSetters, 1 /*B*/),
        };
    }

    // factory methods specify the connection from the wrapper classes to the Mashine

    private static Action<bool>[,] CreateEnabledParameterSetters()
    {
        return new Action<bool>[,]
        {
            { x => Mashine.Enable_A_X = x, x => Mashine.Enable_A_Y = x },
            { x => Mashine.Enable_B_X = x, x => Mashine.Enable_B_Y = x },
        };
    }
    private static IDeviceAxis GetDeviceAxis(Action<bool>[,] enabledSetters, int deviceIndex, int axisIndex)
    {
        return new MachineDeviceAxis
        {
            Enabled = new MachineParameter<bool>(enabledSetters[deviceIndex, axisIndex]),
            Position = null, // TODO
            Start = null, // TODO
        };
    }
    private static IDevice GetDevice(Action<bool>[,] enabledSetters, int deviceIndex)
    {
        return new MachineDevice
        {
            X = GetDeviceAxis(enabledSetters, deviceIndex, 0 /*X*/),
            Y = GetDeviceAxis(enabledSetters, deviceIndex, 1 /*Y*/),
        };
    }

// ...
```

Comment: thank you for the effort. This looks promissing. I am just reading and trying to get it....

Comment: @grek40 Would you have a look at this and see if it could even simplify your approach? https://dotnetfiddle.net/gSd6am

Comment: @Fildor for the question given, yes. But I think the whole idea of `enum Device` and `enum Axis` is just a relict of the messed up implementation in question. And the actual modeling of `IDevice` and `IDeviceAxis` allows a completely different method design to work on the device. It just needs a better usage example.

Comment: Yes, I believe so, too.

Comment: thank you very much for your solution. I agree that my implementation is messed up, otherwise I would not have asked this question. Sorry also for the lack of information in the begining. Ok so far I guess I got most of the approach that you posted. So you created a model of the mashine and a model of the device which represents an entire device with all axes(in contrary to my code) The important trick is the use of the `Action<bool> _setterFunction;` which actually is responsible for the mapping between the object and the corresponding fields in the `Mashine` class.

Comment: @MongZhu Sounds about right. The `Action<bool>` is not really _the important_ trick, but at some point there needs to be code that accesses the actual machine properties by name and I decided to keep this point small with lambda functions. The important part is to have a clean interface of devices and axis that is very flexible and covers everything you actually want to do with the machine. Then just write a machine specific implementation that takes care of the details in a somewhat readable way.

Comment: you are really a great help, and I learned a ton of new stuff today. Especially the use of a setter lambda :) I am trying to modify your code so that I can set a `double` variable. I guess I have to make the `_setterFunction` generic, or is the entire `MachineDevice` bound to `bool` ?

Comment: @MongZhu some more updates on how multiple parameters can be handled without bloating the code to hard.

Comment: @Fildor thank you for your input. I appreciate it very much. Very different and new approach to this problem for me. I definently have a look on it

Comment: My fiddle was a quick and dirty dump of my brain. I think grek40 did a great job of working the idea into a much cleaner and flexible solution.

Comment: @grek40 thank you for the update. the compression of the code looks promising and consise. Although I have to admit that using indices makes it less readable, or introduces a need for a further enum to make it readable for the psychopath who in future has to maintain my code (and knows where I live ;) )

Comment: @grek40 I have to admit that the flexibility in this concept is really good and worth considering it. Thank you again for your time and effort. I learned a lot.

Comment: @grek40 I take back the index part. Your solution is inginious. especially the indexing in the 2 D array, I understood it now entirely. I transformed it a little and have a working solution now with a graspable abstraction level and complexity. Pitty that I can upvote only once ;). Cheers mate